# Как вывести значение функции внутри другой функции/ будучи модулем

Tags: python, функции, return

Пытаюсь разобраться с оператором return. Дан код:

```
def fx(x, y):
    return x / y


def string():
    return "Печатает return"


def main():
    print(fx(6, 2))
    return fx(4, 2)
    print(string())
```

Никак не могу понять, почему функция fx спокойно выводится и внутри этой программы и возвращает `return fx(4,2)` будучи модулем, а вот string() ну никак не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fx(x, y):
    return x / y


def string():
    return "Печатает return"


def main():
    print(fx(6, 2))
    #return fx(4, 2)
    print(string())
    
main()
```

Вот так порпобуйте, return - это оператор возврата из функции, соответственно, до вызова второй функции внутри функции main, программа просто не доходит.

Comment: Вот же... Час сижу перебираю почему он один return выдает, а второй не хочет... А оказывается все так просто. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @MacKenny пожалуйста:), и не забудьте принять ответ